# Pytorch tensor - How to get the indexes by a specific tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor

```
t = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

and a query tensor

```
q = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Is there a way to get the indexes of `q` like

```
indexes = t.index(q) # get back [0, 3]
```

in pytorch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
In [1]: torch.nonzero((t == q).sum(dim=1) == t.size(1))
Out[1]: 
tensor([[ 0],
        [ 3]])
```

Comparing `t == q` performs *element-wise* comparison between `t` and `q`, since you are looking for entire row match, you need to `.sum(dim=1)` along the rows and see what row is a perfect match `== t.size(1)`.

---

As of v0.4.1, [`torch.all()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.ByteTensor.all) supports `dim` argument:

```
torch.all(t==q, dim=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, I do not have torch installed on this PC.

```
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]])
q = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0, 0])

index = torch.nonzero(torch.sum((t == q), dim=1) == t.shape[1])
```

Edit note: edited for the issue raised by Shai.

Comment: your code performs *element-wise* comparison, resulting with `[[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  2],
        [ 0,  3],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  3],
        [ 2,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  0],
        [ 3,  1],
        [ 3,  2],
        [ 3,  3]]`. You need to compare *rows* instead.

Comment: @Shai Ic, that can be easily fixed

Answer (score 0):

A more pytorch native method would be:

```
torch.all(q.repeat((t.shape[1],1))==t, dim=1)
```