# Pytorch Tensor - How to get the index of a tensor given a multidimensional tensor

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pytorch, tensor

I have a the following tensor lets call it **lookup_table**:

```py
tensor([266, 103,  84,  12,  32,  34,   1, 523,  22, 136, 268, 432,  53,  63,
        201,  51, 164,  69,  31,  42, 122, 131, 119,  36, 245,  60,  28,  81,
          9, 114, 105,   3,  41,  86, 150,  79, 104, 120,  74, 420,  39, 427,
         40,  59,  24, 126, 202, 222, 145, 429,  43,  30,  38,  55,  10, 141,
         85, 121, 203, 240,  96,   7,  64,  89, 127, 236, 117,  99,  54,  90,
         57,  11,  21,  62,  82,  25, 267,  75, 111, 518,  76,  56,  20,   2,
         61, 516,  80,  78, 555, 246, 133, 497,  33, 421,  58, 107,  92,  68,
         13, 113, 235, 875,  35,  98, 102,  27,  14,  15,  72,  37,  16,  50,
        517, 134, 223, 163,  91,  44,  17, 412,  18,  48,  23,   4,  29,  77,
          6, 110,  67,  45, 161, 254, 112,   8, 106,  19, 498, 101,   5, 157,
         83, 350, 154, 238, 115,  26, 142, 143])
```

And I have another tensor lets call it **data**, which looks like this:

```py
tensor([[517, 235, 236,  76,  81,  25, 110,  59, 245,  39],
        [523, 114, 350, 246,  30, 222,  39, 517, 106,   2],
        [ 35, 235, 120,  99, 266,  63, 236, 133, 412,  38],
        [134,   2, 497,  21,  78,  60, 142, 498,  24,  89],
        [ 60, 111, 120, 145,  91, 141, 164,  81, 350,  55]])
```

Now I want something which looks similar to this:

```py
tensor([112, 100, ..., 40],
       [7, 29, ..., 2],
       ...,          ])
```

I want to use my data tensor to get the index of the lookup table.
Basically I want to vectorize this:

```py
(lookup_table == data).nonzero()
```

So that this works for multidimensional arrays.

I have read this, but they are not working for my case:
[How Pytorch Tensor get the index of specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863001/how-pytorch-tensor-get-the-index-of-specific-value)
[How Pytorch Tensor get the index of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933781/how-pytorch-tensor-get-the-index-of-elements)
[Pytorch tensor - How to get the indexes by a specific tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703981/pytorch-tensor-how-to-get-the-indexes-by-a-specific-tensor)

**EDIT:**
I am basically searching for an optimized/vectorized version of this:

```py
x_data = torch.stack([(lookuptable == data[0][i]).nonzero(as_tuple=False) for i in range(len(data[0]))]).flatten().unsqueeze(0)
print(x_data.size())
for o in range(1, len(data)):
    x_data = torch.cat((x_data, torch.stack([(lookuptable == data[o][i]).nonzero(as_tuple=False) for i in range(len(data[o]))]).flatten().unsqueeze(0)), dim=0)
```

**EDIT 2 Minimal example:**
We have the **data** tensor:

```py
data = torch.Tensor([
        [523, 114, 350, 246,  30, 222,  39, 517, 106,   2],
        [ 35, 235, 120,  99, 266,  63, 236, 133, 412,  38],
        [555, 104,  14,  81,  55, 497, 222,  64,  57, 131]
])
```

And we have the **lookup_table** tensor, see above.

If we apply this code to the 2 tensors:

```py
 # convert champion keys into index notation
x_data = torch.stack([(lookuptable == x[0][i]).nonzero(as_tuple=False) for i in range(len(x[0]))]).flatten().unsqueeze(0)
for o in range(1, len(data) - 1):
    x_data = torch.cat((x_data, torch.stack([(lookuptable == x[o][i]).nonzero(as_tuple=False) for i in range(len(x[o]))]).flatten().unsqueeze(0)), dim=0)
```

We get an output of this:

```py
tensor([[  7,  29, 141,  89,  51,  47,  40, 112, 134,  83],
        [102, 100,  37,  67,   0,  13,  65,  90, 119,  52],
        [ 88,  36, 106,  27,  53,  91,  47,  62,  70,  21]
       ])
```

This output is what I want, and like I said above its the index of where each value of the tensor data lies on the tensor lookuptable.
The problem is that this is not vectorized.
And I have no Idea how to vectorize it.

Comment: Try giving minimal examples for `lookup_table` and `data` and give the exact output you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `searchsorted`**:

Scanning the whole `lookup_table` array for each input element is quite inefficient. How about sorting the lookup table first (this only needs to be done once)

```
sorted_lookup_table, indexes = torch.sort(lookup_table)
```

and then using `searchsorted`

```
index_into_sorted = torch.searchsorted(sorted_lookup_table, data)
```

If you need an index into the original `lookup_table`, you can get it with

```
index_into_lookup_table = indexes[index_into_sorted]
```

Comment: You might want to rename `sorted` as it is a reserved keyword in Python!

Comment: Ok, it's not reserved and your code will run, yes. But it's considered bad practice to use [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) names as variable names.

Comment: This solution works pretty well, thanks a lot. I didnt know about these methods from pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

Another, faster, approach that **assumes that all values have a limited range, and are `int64`** (Here, I also assume that they are non-negative, but this limitation can be worked around):

Prep work:

```
sorted_lookup_table, indexes = torch.sort(lookup_table)
lut = torch.zeros(size=(sorted_lookup_table[-1]+1,), dtype=torch.int64)
lut[:] = -1 # "not found"
lut[sorted_lookup_table] = indexes
```

Data processing:

```
index_into_lookup_table = lut[data]
```

Comment: when trying to use `lut[sorted_lookup_table] = indexes` I get the error `IndexError: tensors used as indices must be long, byte or bool tensors` even though I tried doing `lut[sorted_lookup_table] = indexes.long()` and the Tensor should be a long Tensor.

Comment: I noticed the other solution is unfortunately not working for me, because in the lookup_table are jumps between the numbers so when I use `sorted_lookup_table, indexes = torch.sort(lookup_table)` I end up with jumps between the numbers.

Comment: @Lupos The original (`lookup_table`) needs to be `long`.