# How Pytorch Tensor get the index of elements?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensor

I have 2 Tensors named **x** and **list** and their definitions are below:

```py
x = torch.tensor(3)
list = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Now I want to get the index of element **x** from **list**. The expected output is an Integer:

```
2
```

How can I do in an easy way?

Comment: this was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863001/how-pytorch-tensor-get-the-index-of-specific-value

Answer (score 7):

```
import torch

x = torch.tensor(3)

list = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
idx = (list == x).nonzero().flatten()
print (idx.tolist()) # [2]

list = torch.tensor([1,2,3,3,5])
idx = (list == x).nonzero().flatten()
print (idx.tolist()) # [2, 3]
```