# PyTorch get indices of value in two-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Given the following tensor (or any random tensor with two dimension), I want to get the index of '101':

```py
tens = tensor([[  101,   146,  1176, 21806,  1116,  1105, 18621,   119,   102,     0,
             0,     0,     0],
        [  101,  1192,  1132,  1136,  1184,   146,  1354,  1128,  1127,   117,
          1463,   119,   102],
        [  101,  6816,  1905,  1132, 14918,   119,   102,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0]])
```

From the related answers I know that I can do something like this:

```py
idxs = torch.tensor([(i == 101).nonzero() for i in tens])
```

But this seems messy and potentially quite slow. Is there a better way to do this that is fast and more torch-y?

Related questions discussing only one-dimensional tensor:

- [How Pytorch Tensor get the index of specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863001/how-pytorch-tensor-get-the-index-of-specific-value)
- [How Pytorch Tensor get the index of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933781/how-pytorch-tensor-get-the-index-of-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `(tens == 101).nonzero()[:, 1]`

```
In [20]: from torch import tensor                                                                       

In [21]: tens = torch.tensor([[  101,   146,  1176, 21806,  1116,  1105, 18621,   119,   102,     0, 
    ...:              0,     0,     0], 
    ...:         [  101,  1192,  1132,  1136,  1184,   146,  1354,  1128,  1127,   117, 
    ...:           1463,   119,   102], 
    ...:         [  101,  6816,  1905,  1132, 14918,   119,   102,     0,     0,     0, 
    ...:              0,     0,     0]])                                                                

In [22]: (tens == 101).nonzero()[:, 1]                                                                  
Out[22]: tensor([0, 0, 0])
```